# How to add c++ compiler to docker container?

Tags: c++, docker

I would like to create a dockerfile which will allow me to use gcc compiler into container. Currently I am using dockerfile generated by VS for my asp net core project.

**My dockerfile:**

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 55712
EXPOSE 44396

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Eunomia.API/Eunomia.API.csproj", "Eunomia.API/"]
COPY ["Eunomia.Insfrastrucutre/Eunomia.Infrastrucutre.csproj", "Eunomia.Insfrastrucutre/"]
COPY ["Eunomia.Core/Eunomia.Core.csproj", "Eunomia.Core/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Eunomia.API/Eunomia.API.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Eunomia.API"
RUN dotnet build "Eunomia.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Eunomia.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Eunomia.API.dll"]
```

**I was trying solution like this:**

```
FROM gcc:4.9
COPY . /usr/src/compiler_cpp
WORKDIR /usr/src/compiler_cpp
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install gcc mono-mcs && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

To add gcc, but that didn't help me still I couldn't reach gcc from container bash.

**Why I need this?**

I need this, becouse I am writing a dot net core web API which allow to check if code writed in c++ is correct by using unit tests.

In advice thanks for help :)

Comment: Why do you thing gcc is not accessible? Or are you saying g++ is not accessible? Have you tried installing the `g++` package?

Comment: When I connect to docker bash by running docker exec -it [container-id] /bin/bash and there write gcc --version or g++ --version i get an error: bash: gcc: command not found.

Comment: _Have you tried installing the g++ package?_. I was just trying to install gcc package in way described in post.